# WordPress software questions on SuperUser.

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, migration

I have recently had a question regarding my WordPress based blog closed.  The closing comment says, "Questions on Super User are expected to generally relate to computer software or computer hardware in some way, within the scope defined in the faq."

The faq says:

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts
>   and power users. If you have a
>   question about …
>
> - computer hardware
> - computer software
>
> and it is not about …
>
> videogames or consoles websites or web
>   services like Facebook, Twitter, and
>   WordPress

My question is about the WordPress software I have installed on my own web site; software that I use, configure, and modify myself.  It is definitely not about my use of the WordPress web site or my consumption of any WordPress web service, and in this case I feel the reason for closing is suspect.

I had another WP question migrated from SuperUser to Web Applications, where the FAQ says the site is for questions covering:

> Using Gmail, Facebook, Twitter,
>   Google, or any other website which
>   behaves like an application
>
> and it is not about …
>
> - Desktop software
> - Apps for mobile devices such as the Android or iPad
> - Hosted scripts such as Wordpress.org and phpBB

Now I have even less clarity on where my questions regarding **my use of** the WordPress **software** stand.  As I mentioned before, I am not using any online WordPress services or web sites.

Let me add that I appreciate the migration of a question, regardless of doubt as to the suitability of the destination, much more than a very quick, summary closing of another question, for the same reasons as the migration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have 2 options for WordPress questions. If they are general usage question you can post to [WebApps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com). There is also a WordPress specific SE site available at [WordPress SE](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com).

Super User is for software locally installed on your computer, which do not use a Web based interface. It's the easiest and simplest definition of what is or is not allowed.

Comment: Thanks Diago, your last paragraph is very clear, and should maybe be included in the FAQ.  I'll check out the WordPress SE site, looks like a much better fit than WebApps.